# How to group data by last 30, 60, 90, 120+ days in Crystal Reports?

Tags: crystal-reports, report, crystal-reports-2008

I have a basic report I'm trying to organize in Crystal based on data from the past 30, 60, 90, 120+ days. So ultimately it should have 4 groups, but when I attempt to  do this with a "Change Group", I only have the ability to select by ranges such as "for each year", "for each month", etc.

I'm pretty sure I would do this with a formula, I just don't know how to structure it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No need for subreports. Create a formula such as:

```
Select CurrentDate - {Purchase.Date}
Case is < 31 : "00-30"
Case is < 61 : "30-60"
Case is < 91 : "60-90"
Default : "Older";
```

Then, simply Group on that formula

Answer (score 0):

Create 4 sub reports one report has 30 days, another has 60 days like till 120+ days and place the reports in report header means each report in one report header section